# Incoming CURL requests from internet not being received by WAMP 2.2 web server

Tags: php, apache, curl, wamp

I have installed a wamp server on my laptop that can be accessed locally and from internet. The domain name is educirajse.com and it points to my IP address 95.180.202.54:81. The http request are forwarded through 2 routers to my local static ip address: 192.168.1.130. My web server is accessible via browser through internet but when I try to access some scripts with CURL from another web server I  receive error 28 - connect timed out. 
I used two different web servers and the situation is the same! The interesting thing is that CURL works locally on WAMP, for example I am able to make payments with paypal and payza via CURL from my WAMP web server, but when I try to send a CURL request from another web server to my wamp web server then I always receive connect timed out or couldn't connect to host...! I tried disabling the firewal but to no avail...!  Here is an example script that fetches a web page, but unfortunately is not able to fetch my web site hosted on educirajse.com through my wamp web server! It fetches all other pages, but not the page hosted on my wamp web server and there is nothing in the error log or access log...!

So, why my WAMP server does not receive CURL request from internet, but receives them locally???

```
    <?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://educirajse.com:81");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 " );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
$res=curl_exec ($curl);
var_dump( curl_getinfo($curl)) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($curl) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($curl) . '<br/>';
echo $res;
curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

Comment: My bet is a firewall is blocking the port. 81 is not a standard port either.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is you have a firewall built into your router OR you have not mapped the ports to point to the computer in question.

If it is port mapping then you will need to login to your router and forward port 81 to the INTERNAL IP of the machine you wish to respond to web server requests on port 80.

I would suggest that you state what router you are using and if you have port forwarding setup or not.  Once we know what router and firmware version that router is running we can better direct you on what to do so that this problem will become a thing of the past.

80 is also not a default port for a web server.. port 80 is the default.  I would still suggest you look into your port forwarding through your router.

I know personally at my home I have setup a static IP to my web server machine and I have forwarded Port 80 to that static IP.

Comment: I finally made it work! :) The problem was not in my port-forwarding nor in my web server! My domain name is pointing to port 81 as configured at Godaddy, so I was unnecessarily attaching port 81 to my domain name (educirajse.com:81)...! I simply removed the port 81 from my domain name and the CURL requests started to be received by my wamp web server...! :) Thanks @JosephCrawford for your assistance...! :)

Comment: Yea port 81 is not a normal port, port 80 is so unless you setup a local server and set it to listen on port 81 it wouldn't hear anything from the outside world :)  Glad your problem is solved.  Please accept this answer if it is the one that helped you with your issue.

Comment: In connection with this I am facing now a real strange issuse! When I use the domain name (educirajse.com)  in CURL I can not get access to my server, but when I use the static IP adress 95.180.202.54:81 of my server I have full access to the php scripts there ...! The domain name educirajse.com works and it points to the static IP address 95.180.202.54:81. The same happens even with the above-mentioned script! Any idea why curl does not want to connect to my web server with my domain name, but it connects with the static IP address?

Comment: I came to the conclusion that everything is fine with my domain and my server, the problem is in the other two servers where CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is disabled...! :(